# Strange type mismatch error with Typed Racket propositions

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I'm experimenting with [propositions in Typed Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/occurrence-typing.html#%28part._propositions-and-predicates%29) and getting a type error I haven't seen before and can't make heads or tails of.

Example code:

```lisp
#lang typed/racket/base
(require racket/fixnum)

; Version of fx= that takes two or more arguments (The TR version only takes 2)
(: fx=? (Fixnum Fixnum Fixnum * -> Boolean))
(define (fx=? a b . nums)
  (and (fx= a b)
       (andmap (lambda ([c : Fixnum]) (fx= a c)) nums)))

(: fxzero? (Fixnum -> Boolean : Zero))
(define (fxzero? i) (fx=? i 0))
```

Trying to compile this gives:

```
demo.rkt:12:20: Type Checker: type mismatch;
 mismatch in proposition
  expected: ((: i Zero) | (! i Zero))
  given: (Top | Top)
  in: (fx=? i 0)
  compilation context...:
```

Using `=` or `fx=` instead will compile and work as expected, and the `fx=?` function is usable elsewhere. Removing the `: Zero` proposition makes it compile and work too.

The expected and given types in that error message aren't in a notation I've seen before, and I can't find mention of it in the documentation. Anyone seen it before, or can explain what's different about my `fx=?` compared to other functions that's breaking my `fxzero?`?

Comment: Finally found an explanation for the `(: i Zero)` and `(! i Zero)` notation at https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Experimental_Features.html#%28part._.Logical_.Refinements_and_.Linear_.Integer_.Reasoning%29 but that doesn't really help with figuring out what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first and largest issue here is that the type that you've applied to your `fx=?` function doesn't have any propositions attached to it, so functions using it aren't going to be able to infer anything about how it operates internally. With that said, I think you're going to have a heck of a time formulating a useful proposition that applies to your `fx=?` function. Specifically, you're asking TR to perform some extremely complex acrobatics through the type of `andmap`.

Put differently: When you formulate propositions like this, I claim TR doesn't go and explore and try to prove things about your code. Instead, occurrence typing means that it's possible to propagate information upward, if this information can be expressed using propositions and if these propositions can be glued together to get the result you want. It also appears that propositions are disallowed on types that include `*` in the argument list.

Just in case this isn't obvious; you know that this program type-checks fine, right?:

```
#lang typed/racket/base

(require racket/fixnum)

(: fxzero? (Fixnum -> Boolean : Zero))
(define (fxzero? i) (fx= i 0))
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware: *Using `=` or `fx=` instead will compile and work as expected*. What I don't get is why that makes a difference; the important part for the proposition on the calling function is it returning true or false, not the internals of a function it calls. I'm not trying to add a proposition to the signature of `fx=?` in this example, just `fxzero?`.

Comment: Let me phrase it this way: how do you know that (your definition of) fxzero? returns true only for booleans? And, followup question, is that reasoning something that you would expect TR to be able to do? If not, this is not going to type-check.